# Meaning of "attached to material"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does **attached to material** means? I heard it in the song [Taking back my love](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/enriqueiglesias/takinbackmylove.html) by Enrique Iglesias. The wording goes like:

> Girl, you're stone cold, you say it ain't so,
>   You already know I'm not attached to material

Answer (score 1):

That would be short for *attached to material things*, i.e. being [*materialistic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/materialistic)

> having a way of thinking that gives too much importance to material possessions rather than to spiritual or intellectual things